# Simplifying Surds, or square root fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I have to write $\sqrt{2\over 18}$ in its simplest form.  How would I work this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sqrt{\frac{2}{18}}=\sqrt{\frac{\frac{2}{2}}{\frac{18}{2}}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{9}}=\frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{9}}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt18}=\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt{2\cdot3^2}}=\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{3^2}}=\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt{2}\cdot3}=\frac13$$

Comment: Why do you do 2x3^2

Comment: Simplification of surd involves moving square numbers out of the surd. For instance, $\sqrt2$ cannot be futhur simplified as 2 is not a perfect square number, while $\sqrt4$ can be simplified 2 as $4=2^2$, is a perfect square number. This is the basic property of surd: $\sqrt{a^2}=a \text{ for } a\ge0$

Comment: Okay,  but I don't understand how you are going from 18, to 2 x 3^2 to 3xsro2

Comment: @user243638: Because the square root of a product (of positive numbers) is the product of the square root of those same numbers.  So $\sqrt{2 \cdot 3^2} = \sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{3^2} = \sqrt{2} \cdot 3$.